# FileMaker 12, multi-table join in portal

Tags: sql, list, user-interface, filemaker

How can I present a multi-table join in a portal, so that I can use the rest of FMP's function for navigation etc? (For example, using `ExecuteSQL`.)

I am talking about such a simple list as a join of the relationships:

```
Country -< District -< City
```

in a list like (maybe not completely correct geographically):

```
Country     District/State     City
---------------------------------------
USA         NY-state           NY-City
Canada      Ontario            Toronto
```

etc.

I can easily show Country and City, but can't show District at the same time...

Comment: What problems are you having adding District to your list? With the relationship you describe, this would usually be as easy as having a portal based on the table City where you add the fields City::Name, District::Name and Country::Name.

Comment: Thanks!

It's a long since I used FMP and I thought I needed ExecutSQL for anything further away, relationshipswise, then the simple parent-child.

Comment: Why not just add district/state and country as calculation fields to the district table, that way you don't have to worry about the joins in the portal?

Comment: Because I am testing the relational capabilities of FMP. I am used to having a backend and doing everything in SQL and then just showing the list in my frontend app. I want real relations so it can scale.

Answer (score 1):

The table relations described are correct. What is needed, however, is what @pft221 is referring to, namely create another table (let's call it `View`), which is related to the `City` table:

```
View::View_id -x- City::City_id.
```

If we then on a `View` table layout put a portal defined by `City`, we can drag all the fields from the three other tables into it (and they will all be correct).

What I did not understand, and still do not completely understand, is *the importance of table occurrences* in FMP (and using the right one).

(Note: if one wants complete freedom from layouts one can use ExecuteSQL, but that requires coding each field.)

Thanks to all helping hands!
*This solution is a translation from one given on [the swedish filemakerforum](http://www.filemakerforum.se).*

Comment: so you have a new *table* for each portal layout? (You're right about the importance of TOs; many FM databases I have seen don't use them very well, their objective seems to be ensure the relationship diagram is connected...!)

Comment: I havent't really sorted this out, but if I make a TO that connects to the 'lowest' bottom grandgrand....child table, I will be able to have a portal that 'sees' all the way 'up' to the 'highest' top grandparent table. 

On the other hand, if I connect my TO to the 'top' grand grand...parent it will only see the grandchildren connected to the first row of each related table in-between,... hmmm.

I don't quite get this yet...

Comment: you can find a file to download at the filemakerforum (link above) if you look at the thread "Visa fält från flera relaterade tabeller i en portal".
You will probably have to join. The tables are easy to understand.

Comment: This is as it's a one-to-many relation, if going the wrong way it picks the first related row. I would advocate (and do in my answer!) grouping TOs by meaning (and using calculation fields), so as to avoid this kind of ambiguity.

Comment: Yes - it is too bad FMP isnät implementing SQL correctly, as one should always get the same rows no matter how you view them, in a relationship.

I can see that having calculation fields can help in some situations, but with a lot of fields, becomes double work. And then the filemaker engine is doing the calculations (?). Then I prefer ExecuteSQL, where one has total control, and probably is using a faster SQL engine. The latter which can be replaced by a backend.

Answer (score 0):

With the relationship you describe, this would usually be as easy as having a portal based on the table City where you add the fields City::Name, District::Name and Country::Name.

Depending on the size of your list, you might want to have a portal search feature or use multiple portals to allow the user to drill down from Country to City.

Comment: Well, I did this and it seemed to work when changing records in the (main) Country table layout, but only when I have one District for each Country. If I have more than one district with associated Citys it will show a table like this:


Canada     Ontario     Toronto

Canada     Ontario     Quebec

Comment: (Edited)  Well, I did this and it seemed to work when changing records in the (main) Country table layout, but only when I have one District for each Country. If I have more than one district with associated Citys it will show a table like this:


Canada, Ontario, Toronto | Canada, Ontario, Quebec etc instead of the correct: Canada, Ontario, Toronto | Canada, Quebec, Quebec. I.e. it shows only the first occurence of District for all portal rows. Can it be done with regular FMP portals?

Comment: I found a way to to it by using ExecuteSQL on a calculated field in the portal and via a parameter selecting the PK of the portal row. But seems like a complicated route for a simple thing?!

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that your City table isn't connected directly to your District table as you have indicated in the question. It sounds like your Table Occurrences could be Country -< City and Country -< District, instead of Country -< District -< City. For the most specific help it would be good to update your question with the following: a) What are your Tables?, b) What are your Table Occurrences?, c) What are the keys used to connect them?, and d) how are the Table Occurrences linked?

Comment: I have in the tables:

Country: Country_pk (numeric, unique, not empty), CountryName

District: District_pk (numeric, unique, not empty), Country_fk, DistrictName

City: City_pk (numeric, unique, not empty), District_fk (numeric), CityName

Comment: (Edited)
  I have in the tables:

Country: Country_pk (numeric, unique, not empty), CountryName

District: District_pk (numeric, unique, not empty), Country_fk, DistrictName

City: City_pk (numeric, unique, not empty), District_fk (numeric), CityName

In the relationships diagram they are connected: Country::Country_pk -< District::Country_fk and District::District_pk -< City::District_fk. Using one copy of eacht table, so three tables interconnected "in-line": Country -< District -< City

Comment: The relationships all look good for everything to work. What Table Occurrence (TO) is your Layout on and what Table Occurrence are you using for the Portal? If your Portal is on the Users table, you should be showing Country::CountryName, District::DistrictName and City::CityName to see the values you are looking for. (Which Cities you see will vary based on the Layout's TO.) You might try creating a new Layout viewing the City TO and add those three fields from the selection box to see if everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to **include both the District/State name and the country name in the cities table** (and the country in the District/State table) as calculation fields.

That is, for TOs `Cities1`, `District/State1` and `Countries1` joined "inline" as you describe, create calculation fields in the Cities table (via the TO `Cities1`):

```
Countries1::CountryName
Distict/State1::DistrictName
```

and a calculation field in the State/District table (via the TO `State/District1`):

```
Countries1::CountryName
```

*You should also set indexing to full.*

In this way, you don't need to worry about how the tables are joined when displaying (or doing more complicated interactions). In fact you could move this set of TOs to one side in your relationship diagram *(grouping and separating TOs is good practice)*.

Comment: Well, I am not specifically interested in solving the Country-District-City problem. I am just using this to examplify a common relationship. I am experimenting with FMP, to see how it can work for me. 

As I said, it can be solved with ExecuteSQL, but since FMP can show Country and City correctly on the same row in a portal, this means that FMP 'knows' which District is correct (since it is using SQL internally, I have learnt). It is strange that it cannot show the correct Districts as easily, since they are 'in-between' so to speak.

Comment: This method is a common idiom, not just for Country-District-City example :)

Comment: This seem like a very complex workaround for showing a related field/column in a list!! So I must add several calculated fields in a table, to be able to show another table! To prevent this is why they invented relational databases.

So it is not possible then in FMP12, as pft221 suggested, to just simply show the column(field) in the portal?!

In this case - since my goal was to show the in-between table column in a portal - I think it is simpler, and more elegant to use ExecuteSQL.

Comment: @Idonodi The thing is, in Filemaker you join TOs rather than tables themselves, if you are viewing the portal from the specific TO you can see related tables... If this is the only issue, why don't you just select those fields in "Add Fields for Portal"? (you can select any field from related tables)